# Subscribes to messenger webhook events using subscribe_apps but it always get reverted to back to feed events only

Tags: facebook

My web application automatically subscribe to  facebook messenger webhook: messages, messages_echo, messages_delivered.
However, sometimes it will automatically revert back to subscribing to feed only. The other subscibed webhook went missing
Anybody having the same issue and how can i resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Does the "auto revert" happen when you switch your app to Live?

Comment: Hi Edrian, nope. no action just automatically reverted.At first, I suspect the issue might be due to user role used for subscribing webhook.  but i tried to use a lower role to subscribe to webook it works.

Comment: If that's the case, you might wanna account for all "subscribe" FB API Calls. There could be a rouge request being sent which could be causing this unexpected change. Find all subscribe calls you might have.

Comment: Yeap.  I will look through the codes again. Thanks!